# object initialization without constructor call

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Today I've encountered a weird behaviour in my C# project while instancing new objects.

```cs
var person = new Person
{
   Firstname = "John",
   Lastname = "Doe"
};
```

As you can see, the objects are initialized without any constructor call, yet it does not throw any errors or warnings. I'm familiar with using object initialization like so:

```cs
var person = new Person() // <- calling the constructor explicitly
{
   Firstname = "John",
   Lastname = "Doe"
};
```

Yet I haven't seen object initialization with *no* constructer-call at all. Can someone explain how and why this works - and if needed, how it differes from the "standard" initalization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As you can see, the objects are initialized without any constructor call

No, that's not the case. It's still calling a constructor, as if `()` were specified explicitly. (That doesn't *necessarily* mean it's calling a parameterless constructor; it could be calling a constructor where all the parameters are optional.)

From [section 12.8.16.2 of the draft C# v7 standard](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/expressions.md#128162-object-creation-expressions):

> An object creation expression can omit the constructor argument list and enclosing parentheses provided it includes an object initializer or collection initializer. Omitting the constructor argument list and enclosing parentheses is equivalent to specifying an empty argument list.